# Update elastic search data with new key-value pair

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

```
{
   "took": 0,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
   "total": 5,
   "successful": 5,
   "skipped": 0,
   "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
"total": 25,
"max_score": 1,
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "surtest1",
    "_type": "catalog",
    "_id": "prod_9876561740",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "id": "01",
      "type": "product" 
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "surtest1",
    "_type": "catalog",
    "_id": "prod_9876543375",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "id": "02",
      "type": "product" 
    }
  }
]
}
}
```

This is the sample json response of search inside elastic search.
We need to add one more key-value pair("spec":"4gb") in all the json object like,

```
"_source": {
      "id": "01",
      "type": "product" ,
      "spec": "4gb"
    },
"_source": {
      "id": "02",
      "type": "product" ,
      "spec": "4gb"
    }
```

this updation should be in a single command.Please guide us to perform this operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
POST /surtest1/_update_by_query?refresh
{
"script": {
    "source": "ctx._source['spec']='4gb'"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Update By Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/docs-update-by-query.html). You are able to prepare [a query to match all documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-match-all-query.html) and use [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/modules-scripting-using.html) to add the property you want.

Example:

```
POST twitter/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.likes++",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "user": "kimchy"
    }
  }
}
```